# OpenVPN doesn't work with some networks

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, vps

i took a vps in OVH, and I installed OpenVPN on it.

Everything works good when i check with my wifi from my smartphone, i have internet, and the tunnel with my vps is ok.

But when i try to connect through the connection of my dormitory, or my university. The connection with my server works fine, but i cannot access to internet. I try several port, like, 1194, 443 and 80, but same result..

Logs when i try to connect from my dormitory for example:

```
Tue Apr 25 14:30:50 2017 Control Channel Authentication: tls-auth using INLINE static key file
Tue Apr 25 14:30:50 2017 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Tue Apr 25 14:30:50 2017 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Tue Apr 25 14:30:50 2017 Socket Buffers: R=[87380->87380] S=[16384->16384]
Tue Apr 25 14:30:50 2017 NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
Tue Apr 25 14:30:50 2017 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]164.132.**:80 [nonblock]
Tue Apr 25 14:30:51 2017 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]164.132.**:80
Tue Apr 25 14:30:51 2017 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
Tue Apr 25 14:30:51 2017 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]164.132.**:80
Tue Apr 25 14:30:51 2017 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]164.132.**:80, sid=ad57bd96 5314ccfe
Tue Apr 25 14:30:52 2017 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=RO, ST=CA, L=Cluj, O=**, OU=**, CN=** CA, name=server, emailAddress=**
Tue Apr 25 14:30:52 2017 VERIFY OK: nsCertType=SERVER
Tue Apr 25 14:30:52 2017 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=RO, ST=CA, L=Cluj, O=**, OU=**, CN=server, name=server, emailAddress=**
Tue Apr 25 14:30:53 2017 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Tue Apr 25 14:30:53 2017 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Tue Apr 25 14:30:53 2017 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Tue Apr 25 14:30:53 2017 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Tue Apr 25 14:30:53 2017 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 2048 bit RSA
Tue Apr 25 14:30:53 2017 [server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]164.132.197.41:80
Tue Apr 25 14:30:55 2017 SENT CONTROL [server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Tue Apr 25 14:30:55 2017 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,route 10.8.0.1,topology net30,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.8.0.10 10.8.0.9'
Tue Apr 25 14:30:55 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Tue Apr 25 14:30:55 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Tue Apr 25 14:30:55 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Tue Apr 25 14:30:55 2017 ROUTE_GATEWAY 10.138.0.1/255.255.0.0 IFACE=wlp2s0 HWADDR=48:e2:44:f4:b4:8d
Tue Apr 25 14:30:55 2017 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Tue Apr 25 14:30:55 2017 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Tue Apr 25 14:30:55 2017 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Tue Apr 25 14:30:55 2017 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Tue Apr 25 14:30:55 2017 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.8.0.10 peer 10.8.0.9
Tue Apr 25 14:30:55 2017 /sbin/ip route add 164.132.197.41/32 via 10.138.0.1
Tue Apr 25 14:30:55 2017 /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.9
Tue Apr 25 14:30:55 2017 /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.9
Tue Apr 25 14:30:55 2017 /sbin/ip route add 10.8.0.1/32 via 10.8.0.9
Tue Apr 25 14:30:55 2017 GID set to nogroup
Tue Apr 25 14:30:55 2017 UID set to nobody
Tue Apr 25 14:30:55 2017 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

And my server configuration:

```
# Which local IP address should OpenVPN
# listen on? (optional)
;local a.b.c.d

# Which TCP/UDP port should OpenVPN listen on?
# If you want to run multiple OpenVPN instances
# on the same machine, use a different port
# number for each one.  You will need to
# open up this port on your firewall.
port 80

# TCP or UDP server?
proto tcp
;proto udp

# "dev tun" will create a routed IP tunnel,
# "dev tap" will create an ethernet tunnel.
# Use "dev tap0" if you are ethernet bridging
# and have precreated a tap0 virtual interface
# and bridged it with your ethernet interface.
# If you want to control access policies
# over the VPN, you must create firewall
# rules for the the TUN/TAP interface.
# On non-Windows systems, you can give
# an explicit unit number, such as tun0.
# On Windows, use "dev-node" for this.
# On most systems, the VPN will not function
# unless you partially or fully disable
# the firewall for the TUN/TAP interface.
;dev tap
dev tun

# Windows needs the TAP-Win32 adapter name
# from the Network Connections panel if you
# have more than one.  On XP SP2 or higher,
# you may need to selectively disable the
# Windows firewall for the TAP adapter.
# Non-Windows systems usually don't need this.
;dev-node MyTap

# SSL/TLS root certificate (ca), certificate
# (cert), and private key (key).  Each client
# and the server must have their own cert and
# key file.  The server and all clients will
# use the same ca file.
#
# See the "easy-rsa" directory for a series
# of scripts for generating RSA certificates
# and private keys.  Remember to use
# a unique Common Name for the server
# and each of the client certificates.
#
# Any X509 key management system can be used.
# OpenVPN can also use a PKCS #12 formatted key file
# (see "pkcs12" directive in man page).
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret

# Diffie hellman parameters.
# Generate your own with:
#   openssl dhparam -out dh1024.pem 1024
# Substitute 2048 for 1024 if you are using
# 2048 bit keys. 
dh dh2048.pem

# Configure server mode and supply a VPN subnet
# for OpenVPN to draw client addresses from.
# The server will take 10.8.0.1 for itself,
# the rest will be made available to clients.
# Each client will be able to reach the server
# on 10.8.0.1. Comment this line out if you are
# ethernet bridging. See the man page for more info.
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

# Maintain a record of client <-> virtual IP address
# associations in this file.  If OpenVPN goes down or
# is restarted, reconnecting clients can be assigned
# the same virtual IP address from the pool that was
# previously assigned.
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

# Configure server mode for ethernet bridging.
# You must first use your OS's bridging capability
# to bridge the TAP interface with the ethernet
# NIC interface.  Then you must manually set the
# IP/netmask on the bridge interface, here we
# assume 10.8.0.4/255.255.255.0.  Finally we
# must set aside an IP range in this subnet
# (start=10.8.0.50 end=10.8.0.100) to allocate
# to connecting clients.  Leave this line commented
# out unless you are ethernet bridging.
;server-bridge 10.8.0.4 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.50 10.8.0.100

# Configure server mode for ethernet bridging
# using a DHCP-proxy, where clients talk
# to the OpenVPN server-side DHCP server
# to receive their IP address allocation
# and DNS server addresses.  You must first use
# your OS's bridging capability to bridge the TAP
# interface with the ethernet NIC interface.
# Note: this mode only works on clients (such as
# Windows), where the client-side TAP adapter is
# bound to a DHCP client.
;server-bridge

# Push routes to the client to allow it
# to reach other private subnets behind
# the server.  Remember that these
# private subnets will also need
# to know to route the OpenVPN client
# address pool (10.8.0.0/255.255.255.0)
# back to the OpenVPN server.
;push "route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0"
;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"

# To assign specific IP addresses to specific
# clients or if a connecting client has a private
# subnet behind it that should also have VPN access,
# use the subdirectory "ccd" for client-specific
# configuration files (see man page for more info).

# EXAMPLE: Suppose the client
# having the certificate common name "Thelonious"
# also has a small subnet behind his connecting
# machine, such as 192.168.40.128/255.255.255.248.
# First, uncomment out these lines:
;client-config-dir ccd
;route 192.168.40.128 255.255.255.248
# Then create a file ccd/Thelonious with this line:
#   iroute 192.168.40.128 255.255.255.248
# This will allow Thelonious' private subnet to
# access the VPN.  This example will only work
# if you are routing, not bridging, i.e. you are
# using "dev tun" and "server" directives.

# EXAMPLE: Suppose you want to give
# Thelonious a fixed VPN IP address of 10.9.0.1.
# First uncomment out these lines:
;client-config-dir ccd
;route 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.252
# Then add this line to ccd/Thelonious:
#   ifconfig-push 10.9.0.1 10.9.0.2

# Suppose that you want to enable different
# firewall access policies for different groups
# of clients.  There are two methods:
# (1) Run multiple OpenVPN daemons, one for each
#     group, and firewall the TUN/TAP interface
#     for each group/daemon appropriately.
# (2) (Advanced) Create a script to dynamically
#     modify the firewall in response to access
#     from different clients.  See man
#     page for more info on learn-address script.
;learn-address ./script

# If enabled, this directive will configure
# all clients to redirect their default
# network gateway through the VPN, causing
# all IP traffic such as web browsing and
# and DNS lookups to go through the VPN
# (The OpenVPN server machine may need to NAT
# or bridge the TUN/TAP interface to the internet
# in order for this to work properly).
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
#push "redirect-gateway" j'ai essayé avec cette simple ligne aussi

# Certain Windows-specific network settings
# can be pushed to clients, such as DNS
# or WINS server addresses.  CAVEAT:
# http://openvpn.net/faq.html#dhcpcaveats
# The addresses below refer to the public
# DNS servers provided by opendns.com.
#push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
#push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"

# Uncomment this directive to allow different
# clients to be able to "see" each other.
# By default, clients will only see the server.
# To force clients to only see the server, you
# will also need to appropriately firewall the
# server's TUN/TAP interface.
;client-to-client

# Uncomment this directive if multiple clients
# might connect with the same certificate/key
# files or common names.  This is recommended
# only for testing purposes.  For production use,
# each client should have its own certificate/key
# pair.
#
# IF YOU HAVE NOT GENERATED INDIVIDUAL
# CERTIFICATE/KEY PAIRS FOR EACH CLIENT,
# EACH HAVING ITS OWN UNIQUE "COMMON NAME",
# UNCOMMENT THIS LINE OUT.
;duplicate-cn

# The keepalive directive causes ping-like
# messages to be sent back and forth over
# the link so that each side knows when
# the other side has gone down.
# Ping every 10 seconds, assume that remote
# peer is down if no ping received during
# a 120 second time period.
keepalive 10 120

# For extra security beyond that provided
# by SSL/TLS, create an "HMAC firewall"
# to help block DoS attacks and UDP port flooding.
#
# Generate with:
#   openvpn --genkey --secret ta.key
#
# The server and each client must have
# a copy of this key.
# The second parameter should be '0'
# on the server and '1' on the clients.
tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
key-direction 0

# Select a cryptographic cipher.
# This config item must be copied to
# the client config file as well.
;cipher BF-CBC        # Blowfish (default)
cipher AES-128-CBC   # AES
auth SHA256
;cipher DES-EDE3-CBC  # Triple-DES

# Enable compression on the VPN link.
# If you enable it here, you must also
# enable it in the client config file.
comp-lzo

# The maximum number of concurrently connected
# clients we want to allow.
;max-clients 100

# It's a good idea to reduce the OpenVPN
# daemon's privileges after initialization.
#
# You can uncomment this out on
# non-Windows systems.
user nobody
group nogroup

# The persist options will try to avoid
# accessing certain resources on restart
# that may no longer be accessible because
# of the privilege downgrade.
persist-key
persist-tun

# Output a short status file showing
# current connections, truncated
# and rewritten every minute.
status openvpn-status.log

# By default, log messages will go to the syslog (or
# on Windows, if running as a service, they will go to
# the "\Program Files\OpenVPN\log" directory).
# Use log or log-append to override this default.
# "log" will truncate the log file on OpenVPN startup,
# while "log-append" will append to it.  Use one
# or the other (but not both).
;log         openvpn.log
;log-append  openvpn.log

# Set the appropriate level of log
# file verbosity.
#
# 0 is silent, except for fatal errors
# 4 is reasonable for general usage
# 5 and 6 can help to debug connection problems
# 9 is extremely verbose
verb 3

# Silence repeating messages.  At most 20
# sequential messages of the same message
# category will be output to the log.
;mute 20
```

I discovered something new, about my network interface. When i'm logged and i have internet i have the following interfaces:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:9754 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9754 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:764318 (764.3 KB)  TX bytes:764318 (764.3 KB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.0.50  P-t-P:10.8.0.49  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:30 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:46 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:3542 (3.5 KB)  TX bytes:7656 (7.6 KB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:e2:44:f4:b4:8d  
          inet addr:192.168.43.214  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e6d3:c6b6:41c7:884f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:110554 errors:0 dropped:1405 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:21761 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:20205981 (20.2 MB)  TX bytes:3316792 (3.3 MB)
```

But when i'm logged without internet from the university network for example i have:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:9255 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9255 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:727090 (727.0 KB)  TX bytes:727090 (727.0 KB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.0.50  P-t-P:10.8.0.49  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:64 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:104 (104.0 B)  TX bytes:3404 (3.4 KB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:e2:44:f4:b4:8d  
          inet addr:172.25.14.156  Bcast:172.25.15.255  Mask:255.255.248.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d1ad:47e3:b9c6:5b09/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:108172 errors:0 dropped:1182 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:21065 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:19807724 (19.8 MB)  TX bytes:3221072 (3.2 MB)
```

Thank you in advance for your response.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `ip route list` or `route -v`  for both when you're connected and its working and when it is not?

Answer (score 0):

@heavyd, when it works:

```
 $ ip route list 
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0 
default via 192.168.43.1 dev wlp2s0  proto static  metric 600 
10.8.0.1 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0 
10.8.0.5 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.6 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0 
164.132.197.41 via 192.168.43.1 dev wlp2s0 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.43.0/24 dev wlp2s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.43.214  metric 600
```

When it is not:

```
$ ip route list 
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0 
default via 10.138.0.1 dev wlp2s0  proto static  metric 600 
10.8.0.1 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0 
10.8.0.5 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.6 
10.138.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.138.0.217  metric 600 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0 
164.132.197.41 via 10.138.0.1 dev wlp2s0 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0  scope link  metric 1000
```